# How do we use regex_replace to manipulate a list with Ansible

Tags: regex, ansible

I have the following data:

```
servers:
  - server1\instance1
  - server2\instance2
  - server2\instance3
```

I need to iterate through each item in the list and remove all characters after and including the backslash. After this I need to remove duplicates and have the unique values defined in another list:

```
hosts:
  - server1
  - server2
```

This is my current playbook:

```
- name: Get unique hosts
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    hosts: "{{ servers | map('regex_replace', '\\.*$', '\\1') | list | unique }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ hosts }}"
```

Running the playbook currently results in the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while templating '{{ servers | map('regex_replace', '\\.*$', '\\1') | list | unique }}'. Error was a <class 'sre_constances.error'>, original message: invalid group reference 1 at position 1
```

I understand this is probably with the way I have written the regex stuff. Appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. First, as the error states your replacement refers to a capture group that doesn't exist in your regex. Since you're trying to get rid of matching characters, the replacement should simply be `''`. Secondly, you have not escaped your backslash in the regex enough; it needs to be escaped for the YAML double-quoted string and also for the regex processing.

```
- name: Get unique hosts
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    unique_hosts: "{{ servers | map('regex_replace', '\\\\.*$', '') | list | unique }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ unique_hosts }}"
```